# Sparql syntax error on nested select

Tags: sparql, fuseki

I am trying to select City with highest population. My Query looks like this:

```
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?population ?capital
WHERE {

    ?x dct:subject dbc:Countries_in_Europe .
    ?x   dbo:capital ?capital .
    ?capital dbo:populationTotal ?population .

     FILTER (?population =
        (
          SELECT MAX(?popul) AS ?pop
          WHERE{
              ?capital dbo:populationTotal ?popul .
          }
        )
  )

}
LIMIT 200
```

I haved followed [This PDF](https://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~cgutierr/papers/subqueriesAMW11.pdf) page 5. 
I am using apache-jena-fuseki-2.4.0 and getting a syntax error 
`Encountered " "select" "SELECT "" at line 18, column 1.`

Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: Where in the linked PDF document (or elsewhere) do you see that the subquery syntax you are using here is supported by Apache Jena Fuseki? From skimming over the paper, it seems the authors propose possible future enhancements of the language. The examples given in the paper are not claimed to be currently supported syntax. You are looking at a "feature request", so to speak, not at a user manual.

Comment: This actualy works even with syntax error but it returns every capital with pop. number ... filter seems to not working as I expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you have seen that you can bind the result of a SELECT query to a variable in the FILTER, but that's totally wrong. This might work for SQL but not for SPARQL.

```
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  dbp:  <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX  dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX  dbc:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX  dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX  db:   <http://dbpedia.org/>

SELECT  ?population ?capital
WHERE
  { ?x        dct:subject          dbc:Countries_in_Europe ;
              dbo:capital          ?capital .
    ?capital  dbo:populationTotal  ?population
    FILTER ( ?population = ?pop )

    # sub-SELECTs are evaluated first and encapsulated by { }
    # in addition (as to TomP's comment), you have to restrict to European captials here
    { SELECT  (MAX(?popul) AS ?pop)
      WHERE
        { ?x        dct:subject          dbc:Countries_in_Europe ;
                    dbo:capital          ?capital .
          ?capital  dbo:populationTotal  ?popul }
    }
  }
LIMIT   200
```

But, if you really want to have the "capital in Europe with the highest population", why not using the easier and more obvious way which reflects your task, i.e. `ORDER BY` + `LIMIT 1`:

```
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  dbp:  <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX  dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX  dbc:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX  dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX  db:   <http://dbpedia.org/>

SELECT  ?population ?capital
WHERE
  { ?x        dct:subject          dbc:Countries_in_Europe ;
              dbo:capital          ?capital .
    ?capital  dbo:populationTotal  ?population    
  }
ORDER BY DESC(?population)
LIMIT   1
```

Comment: "I don't know where you have seen that you can bind the result of a SELECT query to a variable in the FILTER, but that's totally wrong." - it's in the paper linked in the question. However, it seems like the paper does not seem to be saying "This works in current software.", but rather "SPARQL might be extended like this in the future."

Comment: U sait that sub-Select is evaluated as first, so u need to add more to it. ?x        dct:subject          dbc:Countries_in_Europe ;
              dbo:capital          ?capital .  Need to be added as well. Then it will work

Comment: @TomP You're right. I didn't check what the goal of the query is, but I guess he wants to have the capital in Europe with the highest population. But that's easier to solve with `ORDER BY DESC(?population)` + `LIMIT 1`

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The paper you mentioned is a research paper but has nothing to do with the SPARQL 1.1 standard, so I wouldn't rely on things that are mentioned there.

Comment: @AKSW: That's exactly what I wrote, isn't it?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You mean my comment regarding the paper or the SPARQL queries? W.r.t. the former yes, the latter no.

Comment: @AKSW: I meant the comment regarding the paper.

Comment: @AKSW I knew about the second one but when you are at school, u need to know the harder way :) ... anyway thaks